# How do I set text cursor height to match with my font in EditText

Tags: android, fonts, android-edittext, typeface

I am using [Digory Doodles Font](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/digory-doodles) for my `EditText`. Font is locally available to my app in assets.

When I set this font to my `EditText`, the text cursor takes too much space in height. It doesn't match actual text height. This, also, changes height for `EditText`, which was set to `wrap_content`.

This is how I set fonts:

```
val typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(
   assetsManager, "fonts/$type/$fileName"
)
editText.typeface = typeface
```

When I set font it looks like image below.

[image]

If I move cursor to some other position in text(not last position), it looks like image below:

[image]

For any other font, it looks like image below:

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: This is not going to be of much help, but I believe that the font is malformed at least for Android, although it may work in other places. If you look at the character map, you will see that the characters are out of the bounding box. You can see that [here](https://www.1001fonts.com/digory-doodles-font.html#character-map). I would look for another font to use unless you think that you can fix this one.

Answer (score 0):

`android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"`

Design custom cursor and use like this